# Another use of gratia as in exempli gratia

Tags: meaning, example-request

A web search tells us that e.g. stands for exempli gratia where gratia has the literal translation of “for the sake of”. Can anyone give another example from the literature where gratia has this meaning but not in this phrase?

Comment: [Ex gratia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_gratia) (as in non-prescribed compensation) on its lonesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is outlined in the Lewis and Short [entry](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dgratia):

> A. **grātĭā (acc. to II. A.), lit., in favor of, on account of, for the sake of; hence, in gen., on account of (usually placed after the gen., in Quint. a few times before it; cf.: causa, ergo).**
> (α). With gen.: “sed neque longioribus quam oportet hyperbatis compositioni serviamus, ne quae ejus gratia fecerimus, propter eam fecisse videamur,” lest what we have done to embellish the style we should seem to have done merely on account of the construction we had chosen, Quint. 9, 4, 144: “tantum abest, ut haec bestiarum etiam causa parata sint, ut ipsas bestias hominum gratia generatas esse videamus,” Cic. N. D. 2, 63, 158: tu me amoris magis quam honoris servavisti gratia, Enn. ap. Cic. Tusc. 4, 32, 69 (Trag. v. 316 Vahl.); cf.: “honoris gratia nomino,” Cic. Quint. 7, 28: “nuptiarum gratia haec sunt ficta atque incepta omnia,” Ter. And. 5, 1, 17: “simulabat sese negotii gratia properare,” Sall. J. 76, 1: hominem occisum esse constat; “non praedae gratia: quia inspoliatus est,” Quint. 7, 1, 33; cf.: “hereditatis gratia,” id. 5, 12, 5: “quem censores senatu probri gratia moverant,” Sall. C. 23, 1: “profectus gratia dicere,” Quint. 2, 10, 9: “brevitatis gratia,” id. 4, 2, 43: “decoris gratia,” id. 8, 6, 65: “difficultatis gratia,” id. 9, 2, 77: “aut invidiae gratia ... aut miserationis,” id. 9, 2, 8: “praesentis gratia litis,” id. 2, 7, 4 al.

Comment: Boy, that first example gives me headaches, and it does not exactly help that what L & S translate as "on account of" here is actually *propter*, whereas they translate *ejus gratia* as "to embellish the style " ‍

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel My eyes glossed right over that example to the easier ones below!

Comment: @cmw: In the Quintillian quote L&S didn't translate the first line, "sed neque longioribus quam oportet hyperbatis" = "but don't you exaggerate for longer than is necessary"--is that correct? Why is "longer" in the plural?

Answer (score 4):

Art for art's sake: ars gratia artis.